# nest mongoose document to another collection document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How to save .text of commentSchema as array format in the field of .comments  in reviewSchema?

of course each review (post) has multiple comments.

```js
// Connect to the db using mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/reviewdb")

// setting up model and schema for comment
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
  text: String,
  user : String,
  username: String,
  date: Date
});

// setting up model and schema for reviews

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
  text: String,
  user : String,
  username: String,
  mydate: Date,
  likes:{type: Number, "default":0, min:0},
  comments:[commentSchema]
});

// setting up model for review
var Review = mongoose.model('review', reviewSchema);

// setting up model for comment
var comment = mongoose.model('comment', reviewSchema);
```

Comment: Why do you use reviewSchema when setting comment model?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I dont know kindly show me right path if it is wrong please.

Comment: here `var comment = mongoose.model('comment', reviewSchema);`  replace reviewSchema with `commentSchema`

Comment: @SuleymanSah can I contact you  separately , may be you help me as a freelancer? it is a small task for you may be.